# String was passed as argument, but in the function it turned out to be a Rec

Tags: java, android, arguments

[image]I was developing an android app using java language. 
 The body of the method was below: a string "3" was passed to it as first argument--nextCmdId, but in the method it turned out to be a Rect, and the application crashed.
 Quite odd!! 
thanks
BR
shawn

```
public String formatSyncTagPreamble(String nextCmdId,
                                    String sourceName,
                                    String sourceUri)
{

    StringBuffer syncTag = new StringBuffer();

    syncTag.append("<CmdID>").append(nextCmdId)
           .append("</CmdID>\n")
           .append("<Target><LocURI>")
           .append(sourceUri)
           .append("</LocURI></Target>\n")
           .append("<Source><LocURI>")
           .append(sourceName)
           .append("</LocURI></Source>\n");

    return syncTag.toString();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Providing more information may help get an answer. For example, please explain how you determined that "it turned out to be a Rect".  If there is pertinent output, please show it.  Show the code that calls `formatSyncTagPreable`.  If there was an exception, please show it.

Comment: What do you mean `a Rect`? I think you better debug your program using some well placed log statements.

Comment: @qiuping345: It would also help if you asked a question.

Comment: Could be a namespace collission -like thing? Eclipse might just be confused and showing you the info about the 'other' `nextCmdId` ?

Comment: There's no other method with the same name. It's quite odd, I cannot believe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that Eclipse knows this as a .class file. Did you attach the correct source for SyncMLFormatter? (I agree with @Bozho...a String cannot change into a Rect in Java.)